# Decode a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a string which i save in db looks like this : Anders Mæåø

On server i have a folder named : TestFolder

in TestFolder i have 3 other folders Named :

Anders Mæåø
Timothy Jones
Will Smith

When i am getting string  "Anders Mæåø" from Db and run a loop to search in TestFolder for folder name Anders Mæåø it returns null.

**Sample Code:**

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase fileData, 
                                String ProjectName, string userName)
{
    var fileName =
    this.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + userName + "/" + ProjectName + "/" +
              System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName)));
    fileData.SaveAs(fileName);


    return Content(fileName);
}
```

if userName is Anders it will upload withour problem, but if username is Andøers it wouldnt caus it cant find the correct folder. same with projectName

any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "language pack" but are those the appropriate Unicode characters you'd expect to see? It's not clear where the problem is here...

Comment: Did you check permissions? If folders are there, you're sure about it and you enumerate only one of them then maybe others are not accessible.

Comment: probabbly server is not able to create a folder with the specified name, as it's not supported by  its encoding..

Comment: Please provide code, and it may be helpful, if you post the strings the string your code actually finds in the loop.

Comment: Updated with code sample

Comment: Any suggestion? Yes, use user ID to create the folder, instead of user name! ;)

Comment: it wouldnt work for admin part, admin should be able to find around easily and fast. but still same problem will be for project name

Comment: I think this is a risky proposition. If the username or worse project name is any string, there are all kinds of characters that are prohibited in folder names. I would second the user ID proposition and build an admin piece to make administration easier. Having said that if you want to proceed with your approach, what is your Upload folder saving to? An NTFS volume?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to change your `UTF-Encoding`.

Have a look at this sample project about [Using Character Encoding in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6515/Using-Character-Encoding-in-ASP-NET)

Also have a look at this article about [Select an Encoding for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx)

Comment: well i think i found where it fails.. it fails on the way from view to controller